# What does "putting your head into my mouth" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, collocation

The following passage is from the novel Ivanhoe by Walter Scott.

> "By St Dunstan," answered Gurth, "thou speakest but sad truths; little
>   is left to us but the air we breathe, and that appears to have been
>   reserved with much hesitation, solely for the purpose of enabling us to
>   endure the tasks they lay upon our shoulders. The finest and the fattest
>   is for their board; the loveliest is for their couch; the best and
>   bravest supply their foreign masters with soldiers, and whiten distant
>   lands with their bones, leaving few here who have either will or the
>   power to protect the unfortunate Saxon. God's blessing on our master
>   Cedric, he hath done the work of a man in standing in the gap; but
>   Reginald Front-de-Boeuf is coming down to this country in person, and we
>   shall soon see how little Cedric's trouble will avail him.--Here, here,"
>   he exclaimed again, raising his voice, "So ho! so ho! well done, Fangs!
>   thou hast them all before thee now, and bring'st them on bravely, lad."
>   "Gurth," said the Jester, "I know thou thinkest me a fool, or thou
>   wouldst not be so rash in putting thy head into my mouth. One word to
>   Reginald Front-de-Boeuf, or Philip de Malvoisin, that thou hast
>   spoken treason against the Norman,--and thou art but a cast-away
>   swineherd,--thou wouldst waver on one of these trees as a terror to all
>   evil speakers against dignities."

I wonder what exactly the Jester meant when he said
"thou wouldst not be so rash in putting thy head into my mouth."

Comment: It's a reference to the cliche of metaphorically [putting your head in the **lion's** mouth](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070227170917AAncDTK)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If you don't mind, can you make that an actual answer? I'd like to get this question off of the Unanswered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a reference to the cliche of metaphorically [putting your head in the lion's mouth](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070227170917AAncDTK).

Apologies for the substantial "cut&paste", but I'm concerned about "link rot"...

> Back in the days when a circus would travel from town to town, most would have a lion tamer (a guy who had trained lions and other large animals). One standard trick would be for the trainer to have one lion open his mouth; the tamer would actually put his head in the lion's mouth to show how well trained the animal was.
>
> Since then, "putting your head in the lion's mouth" means knowingly doing something dangerous.